# How to setting Core file size in Docker container?

Tags: docker, coredump, limits, ulimit, dockerfile

I want to set core file size to unlimited in a Docker container.

I tried changing `limits.conf` in container.

#### Dockerfile

```
RUN sed -i.bak '/\# End of file/ i\\* soft core unlimited' /etc/security/limits.conf
RUN sed -i.bak '/\# End of file/ i\\* hard core unlimited' /etc/security/limits.conf
```

I restarted the container but that didn't work.

Core file size is always 0.

I can use the command

```
$ ulimit -c unlimited
```

for setting core file size. But I have to use the command for another application.
So I don't want us these commands.

Please let me know how I can change the core file size in a Docker container.

Answer (score 7):

You can set the limits on the container on `docker run` with the `--ulimit` flag.

```
docker run --ulimit core=<size> ...
```

Note that "unlimited" is not a supported value since it is not actually a real value, but `-1` is equivalent to it:

```sh
$ docker run -it --ulimit core=-1 ubuntu:18.04 sh -c 'ulimit -a | grep core'
coredump(blocks)     unlimited
~ $
```

Comment: If we want to change it permenantly what we can use? Can we push above line docker run --ulimit core=<size> to the file /etc/security/limits.conf.

Comment: You can set this at the daemon level `--default-ulimit core=<size>`

Comment: Thanks. its working.. but if i run 'docker run --ulimit core=9999999999 -ti -d --volumes-from test-vol-$5 -p $1:13456 -e "test_prod_id=$2" -e "ip_v4_address=$4" test:$5' i can able to see the limits for container root. But i am not able login other users of container from container root. Is there any mistake in above command?